# .NET Message Queuing using SQL Server as Message Storage

Tags: .net, message-queue

I'm looking for a MSMQ alternative which use SQL Server as messages persistance since MSMQ as some limitations : 4Mb Message Size, 1.6Go Queue Size ...

Is there any open source or free project doing that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short article on using a table as a queue.  Its a couple year old but I've used the technique in the past and it works quite well.

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1257

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702379/queuing-in-oneway-wcf-messages-using-windows-service-and-sql-server ?